# What's VT-style mouse mode?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wikipedia, tmux

I'm trying to figure out how to copy from WSL(vim visual mode selection, tmux copy mode selection) and paste to Windows.

I saw the jargon `VT-style mouse mode` in [this post](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1586#issuecomment-272235493), then tried to search it, which ended up finding no good explanation. And even no related item in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DEC VT-series terminals are the original hardware terminals which most software terminal emulators now emulate. There are various different mouse modes which modern terminal emulators support (many of which appeared after the original DEC terminals) documented here: https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Mouse-Tracking

The use of this phase in the thread you linked to means one or more of these mouse modes.